# JavaScript Logic With Timing and Events

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, dom-events, timing

Have a broad algorithmic question regarding the Flow of Logic using `setTimeout()` and Events `.onclick()` in JavaScript.

**Basic Procedure:**

> When a button is clicked 2 times within 3 seconds, a HTML element
> (currently visible) dissapears, following this, when the same button
> is pressed the image reappears and the process repeats

What would be the best way to come about this problem? Outline of code is appreciated.

Have been working on this for several hours now, my code written is logically incorrect and would not be much good use.

Comment: Please post some relevant code. It's hard to give you tips when we don't know what you are doing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g5gus7pt/1/ Something like this? Click on the “0” twice within 3 seconds and it’ll change to “1”. Repeat it to reverse it. If the button only needs to be clicked once to reverse it you can change it accordingly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g5gus7pt/2/ This, if the reversal only needs one click.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this could help:

http://jsfiddle.net/kqzdn8xe/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button1').click(function(){
        if (typeof(this.visibleFlag) == 'undefined') {
            this.visibleFlag = true;
        }
        var thisTimeClick = Date.now();

        if (this.prevClick && (thisTimeClick - this.prevClick < 3000) && this.visibleFlag) {
            this.visibleFlag = false;
            $('#div1').hide();
        } else if (!this.visibleFlag) {
            this.visibleFlag = true;
            $('#div1').show();
        }

        this.prevClick = thisTimeClick;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are after something like this;

I have also included logic to ignore the case of a 3rd successive click (within 500ms of the 2nd one), as I assume you are after double click like behavior.

It would be worth also looking at the jQuery double click event: https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

```
<button id="buttonExample">Click me</button>
<br/>
<div id="imageContainer">Image</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#buttonExample').click(function(){

 var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
 var lastClicked = parseInt($('#buttonExample').data("lastClicked")||0);
 var ms = timeNow - lastClicked;

 if($("#imageContainer").is(":visible")) {

  if(ms < 3000) {
    $("#imageContainer").hide();
  }

  $('#buttonExample').data("lastClicked", timeNow);

 }else if(ms > 500){

  $("#imageContainer").show();

 }

});

</script>
```